# SharpDX.Windows missing?

Tags: c#, sharpdx

First and foremost, I apologize if this is the wrong place to ask this question, I just can't find the answer anywhere else.

I've imported the SharpDX references into my C# project, however, the SharpDX.Windows reference isn't there. I've tried downloading it from the website and using NuGet, however with both of them the reference doesn't exist.

Does anyone know how to fix this or what is causing the issue?

Comment: isn't SharpDX is not longer supported/developed? Like XNA, i think it is abandoned.

Comment: I'm not actually sure. It was last updated in March I think, but regardless I feel as if it should still have the references. It's possible that it's no longer supported though.

Comment: I know this is an older post, but FYI, the latest update to the SharpDX NuGet packages is 4.0.1 on the 31st May 2017. Looks like it's still supported.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your target is the desktop you will need to load the SharpDX.Desktop assembly from NuGet.

Comment: Thank you very much! The tutorial I was looking at didn't mention that.